# SQL to replace all occurrences from table using REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to know how I can replace all occurrences (from any column in a table) of `\\\\N` with an empty string. I think I should use the REGEX_REPLACE function, but I've only been able to see examples of it used on one column inside Snowflake.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( <subject> , <pattern> [ , <replacement> , <position> , <occurrence> , <parameters> ] )
```

Comment: It is not needed `REGEXP_REPLACE`, just use `replace` function to convert `\\\\N` to `''`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the SQL to operate on each column using the 'show columns' then build a set of SQL statements using the lastqueryID

```
show columns in table mytable;
select 'update mytable set ' || "column_name" || ' = replace(' || "column_name" || ',''\\\\\\\\N'','''',);'  from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not possible natively in SQL. You could do

```
update your_table
set col1=replace(col1,'\\\\N',''),
    col2=replace(col2,'\\\\N',''),
    col3=replace(col3,'\\\\N',''),
    ....
```

I personally prefer the following because I can run the select portion to take a look at my output before making any changes

```
create or replace table your_table as

select top 0 * --to avoid having to write column names in subsequent select
from your_table
union all
select replace(col1,'\\\\N',''),
       replace(col2,'\\\\N',''),
       replace(col3,'\\\\N',''),
       ...
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that Snowflake by default replaced NULL values with `\\N` that's why I was seeing the exported file from my s3 bucket containing a double escaped newline characters. The issue wasn't a problem with the table itself but after export and setting the file_format option to override the default as empty did the trick.

```
copy into <@s3..> from <view> header = true max_file_size = 5368709120 Single=True overwrite = true file_format = (TYPE='CSV' COMPRESSION='NONE' DEFAULT_NULL=());
```